# The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1 Error

Tags: c, gcc, exit-code

When I tried to run this `C` code in Visual Studio Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num, i = 0, lowest;

    int array[10];

    while(i != 10) 
    {
        printf("Please write %d. integer.\n\n", i);
        if(scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
            i = i + 1;
             // Clear the input buffer
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            continue; // Restart the loop
            
            if(i == 1) {
                lowest = num;
            } else if(lowest > num || lowest == num) {
                lowest = num;
            }
        }
       
    }
    
    printf("Lowest number in array is %d. ", lowest);

    return 0;
}
```

It says:
The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1

and I selected "Debug anyway". Also this one doesn't solves my problem.

I expect to my program work but it didn't worked for some reasons.
I thought it was about `mingw` but I already installed that.

Comment: You need to look at the build-log. It's possible that you have a build-error.

Comment: It seems you have seen some code to handle input, but didn't quite understand how it work and wrote your own version of it. The problem is that it's not doing what you think it's doing. I'm talking about the "clear the input buffer" part, and the whole validation of correct integer input. It's just wrong. Either you will not set `lowest` and print whatever its indeterminate value might be. Or you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: Did you successfully build and run a HelloWorld? What description did you use to do the setup of your environment? (I ask because many users have problems with VSC and many of those because they did not thoroughly do the setup and often because they followed and incomplete or wrong description.)

Comment: @Some programmer dude I searched for build log but I can't find it. I'm pretty new to Visual Studio Code and C programming. So can you give me detailed expression please ?

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried it now. It didn't worked ın right bottom corner of screen there was error:

Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file.

Comment: See? If you cannot even build a HelloWorld then the problem is in the setup. So, answer my other question and give details on how you set your environment up.

Comment: VSCode is not a beginner-friendly code editor. Do not recommend.

Comment: @Yunnosch I watched some youtube video how to setup it, but it didn't work out for me so ı watched another video. I might be installed the same thing twice ıdk. So ı should remove all stuff then make clean setup right ?

Comment: If you would clearly state which description/manual/documentation/tutorial/video you followed then people here might be able to tell you whether it is complete and accurate. Would you like to link to what you followed? You do understand that "a video" and "another video" as a description do not offer that same possibility, right? However, trying from scratch if something failed is a widely spread general concept.

Comment: The vast majority of all videos online are not of highest quality. Please take some time  to read [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) instead. Its [section for GCC on Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) is very good.

Comment: @Yunnosch I followed this video for setup: https://youtu.be/9VE7p-he4fA?si=HlxrKd6wIoj3GB9K
I can't find the "another video" unfortunately, but it wasn't as important as first one for setup.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Documentation you send is about C++ not C as mentioned in video and left side of website, ıt is in C++ category ; but it requires extension called C / C++ so is that true documentation for me as ı want to code in C language.

Comment: The only difference between building a C or C++ program with GCC, is that the C source files are ending in `.c` and are built by `gcc`, and the C++ source files end in `.cpp` (or similar) and are built by `g++`. Other than that, it's almost all the same. The important bits are the installation and configuration of the plugin and its configuration files, besides installing MinGW itself (or better yet MSYS2, which is a bigger environment with more tools).